# not getting the dropdowns in laravel excel

Tags: php, excel, laravel-5.7

```
            $parse   = new SiteInput();
            $parse = $parse->MultipleSite();

            //set drop down column for phase 1
            $drop_phase1 = 'H';
            $p1 = array(); 
            foreach ($parse['levels'] as $phase1s) {
                $p1[] = $phase1s->desc;
            }
            $validation=$event->sheet->getCell("{$drop_phase1}4")->getDataValidation();
            $validation->setType(DataValidation::TYPE_LIST);
            $validation->setErrorStyle(DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION);
            $validation->setAllowBlank(false);
            $validation->setShowInputMessage(true);
            $validation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
            $validation->setShowDropDown(true);
            $validation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
            $validation->setError('Value is not in list.');
            $validation->setPromptTitle('Pick from list');
            $validation->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');
            $validation->setFormula1(sprintf('"%s"', implode(',', $p1)));
            for ($i = 4; $i <= 1000; $i++) {
                $event->sheet->getCell("{$drop_phase1}{$i}")->setDataValidation(clone $validation);
            }
```

> When I give the default array like $p1=['option','option 2']; this works but i want the list from my DB

[image: got after clicking yes in 2nd pic]

[image: First error]

Answer (score 0):

Just change the variable name and it done
variable is overriding $parse